# How to read qemu fw_cfg value in windows guest?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

Unable to find information about how to read `-fw_cfg` value in windows guest with the help of this: https://github.com/virtio-win/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/tree/master/fwcfg

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70967245/625521

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer here: https://github.com/virtio-win/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/issues/880#issuecomment-1424372011
that currently there is no easy way to get fw_cfg values.